# Cast object to base or derived class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Is there any difference between:

```
cBase* object = new cDerived();
```

and

```
cDerived* object = new cDerived();
```

If so, in which cases do I choose one over the other?

Comment: What's the difference between `cBase *object;` and `cDerived *object;`?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that they declare `object` as having different types, which can have lots of consequences. For example:

- If `cDerived` declares any new members (beyond what it inherits from `cBase`), then only the version with `cDerived* object` makes those available (unless you explicitly downcast back to `cDerived*`).
- If `cBase` declares any non-virtual member functions that `cDerived` overrides, then which one gets called depends on the type of the pointer that you use to call it.
- If a function expects to take a `cDerived*`, then you can't pass it a `cBase*` (unless you explicitly downcast back to `cDerived*`).

Answer (score 2):

The static type of `object` differs in your two examples.  Let's take an example:

```
struct A {};

struct B : A
{
    void method() {}
};

int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    B* b = new B;
    a->method(); // compile error, A has no member named method.
    b->method(); // fine. b's static type is B*, and B has a member named method
}
```

It doesn't matter that `a` actually points to a `B` object; its static type is `A*` and `A` has no member named `method`.